# Is it possible to know what type of change (add, delete, change) that triggered ValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to know what type of change that triggered ValueEventListener. something like this:

```
        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     if(childAdded)
                            Do something
                      else if(childDeleted)
                            Do something
                      else
                            Do something
                }
    
        }
```

I know ChildEventListener has the add remove methods, but it won't work for me so please don't suggest to use it.